# Is there a Django app to aggregate/consolidate notifications to be mailed at once?

Tags: django, email, notifications, django-mailer

Today our website emails the user for every "event" who needs to be notified, but the number of "notifications" is becoming huge, annoying our users with tons of daily emails. Instead, I want to aggregate the notifications and send only one email every day.

I found this project, who seems to be exactly what I need: http://code.google.com/p/django-mailer/

> A reusable Django app for queuing and throttling of email sending, scheduled sending, **consolidation of multiple notifications** into single emails and logging of mail failures.
>
> Sample Use Cases:
>   (...)
>
> - a user doesn't want individual emails for each notification but wants them in digest form (e.g. a daily digest of new posts or a weekly update on friends who have joined)
>
> (...)
>
> NOTE: Now moved to http://github.com/jtauber/django-mailer/

Looks cool, but there are no code at all doing this at the Github repo and there are no more code at Google Code.

Do you know some alternative? (other than code it myself)

Comment: Work through the django-mailer code to find out how to aggregate the mail. Might be less work than writing your own.

Comment: So... what's the issue with using Github?

Comment: I love Github, but the code there seems to do not what the Google Code description says. I read the Github code and found anything related to this feature. Is not broken, is simple not there!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need some service running in the background, otherwise what would trigger the email batch? I would use [django celery email](http://paulm.us/post/885869589/release-django-celery-email) to do this. You'll need to set up [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) first.

Comment: The project docs at Google Code teaches to set some cronjobs. Btw, I prefer to use Celery, who is already set in my environment.